# How to control whether Python uses OpenCV2 or OpenCV3?

Tags: python-2.7, opencv

On Linux with Python 2.7 there is usually `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/{dist,site}-packages/cv.{so,py}`, but how can I tell which version of OpenCV I have there? Is it possible to install both and switch between them, or to force a particular version?

Note: `pip freeze | grep opencv` returns nothing at all even though I can use `import cv2`.

Comment: You can check what you are using by `pip freeze | grep opencv`

Comment: "Is it possible to install both and switch between them" yes! Install them into virtual environments. This is true of any Python library---virtual environments save the day. I have three different OpenCV versions installed on my system!

Comment: @user1767754 That returned nothing! I definitely have OpenCV installed as I use it in various scripts, and `import cv2` works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 options.

> 1) You can check it with pip. Outputs installed packages in requirements format.

```
pip freeze
or
pip freeze | grep opencv
```

> 2) From within python

```
import cv2
print cv2.__version__
>'3.3.0'
```

Comment: That answers half my question - I have 2.4.13. My Ubuntu install is a horrible hybrid of repository code and self-built that dies if I try to install OpenCV 3, though, but I can use that to test code for compatibility on another machine that can be verified to have 3.x.

Comment: Ok, so you probably didn't install opencv with pip then. Furthermore to have clean python, you should use `virtualenv` to create as many clean environment as you want.